# Multiple Authentication in Laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I have a got a situation where Staff Model has various roles and User Model also has various roles. I am using default authentication for User Model. But I am struck on how to use the Auth library for Staff Model too.

I found https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth/, but it does not support for laravel5.

So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Checkout the answer I wrote here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192535/how-to-use-authentication-for-multiple-tables-in-laravel-5/32822341#32822341

Answer (score 1):

you have another git source available for laravel 5:

https://gist.github.com/danielcoimbra/64b779b4d9e522bc3373

It's more a native way of doing that.
I believe that's what you're looking for, I used it as well and it works like a charm.
good luck :)