# laravel attempt for more then one table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, login-attempts

How can I use more the one table to attempt login ?

I tried following setting, but it will change to use Admin::class, and the User::class attempt will fail immediately.

**app/config**

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => FACI\Entities\User::class,
            'model' => FACI\Entities\Admin::class,
        ],
]
```

this is my attempt

```
$attempt = \Auth::attempt([
      'name' => $this->request->name,
      'password' => $this->request->password,

]);
```

How to told the code to binding the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use authentication for multiple tables in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192535/how-to-use-authentication-for-multiple-tables-in-laravel-5)